# Accessing to DOM functions from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

There is a need to access to DOM functions from Firefox extension.

I have code that works perfectly from Firefox console:

```
var chk = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=checkbox]' );
for (var i=0; i < chk.length; i++)
{
    if (!(chk[i].disabled))
    {
        chk[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

I want to make a simple extension for Firefox in order to don't copy-paste this code each time. But I've faced with issue that cannot access to DOM functions from main.js.

Could you please advise a way to solve this issue?

Note:

Found this solution but it didn't help:

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var window = wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var document = window.document;
```

Comment: When you use DOM functions you are using it on some document obviously. So use that document's scope to access it's DOM functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.js` will be run only once, and not for each window or tab.

Either use a [`PageMod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) content-script or attach a content script via [`tabs.attach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29).

The content script would be your `querySelectorAll` snippet, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I know people won't like me recommending this to you, they want you to use PageMod etc but I want to share with you because I see your mind was on a certain track, and PageMod just is complet off that track. You were in the right direction so nice job there. It reminds me of how I had to figure things out.

When you use DOM functions you are using it on some document obviously. So use that document's scope to access it's DOM functions.

If the document is your most recent document used then do this:

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var window = wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var document = window.contentDocument;

var chk = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=checkbox]' );
for (var i=0; i < chk.length; i++)
{
    if (!(chk[i].disabled))
    {
        chk[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

notice the window.contentDocument vs the window.document that you had. The window object returend by the `geMostRecentBrowserWindow` is a BROWSER window, not the HTML window I think you were expecting. For that you'll have to access it's `contentDocument`.

Now if the document is not the the currently selected tabs document then you have to identify the document of your tab like this:

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var window = wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
if (window.gBrowser && window.gBrowser.tabContainer) { //this checks to make sure it has tabs
    var tabs = window.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
    var myTab;
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].linkedBrowser.contentDocument.location.href = 'my url') {
            myTab = tabs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!myTab) {
        console.warn('Could not find tab with location.href == "my url"');
    } else {
        var document = myTab.contentDocument;

        var chk = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
            if (!(chk[i].disabled)) {
                chk[i].checked = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now if you have multiple browser windows open, then you'll have to go through all the windows and then run the code above to go through all the tabs in each window. If you want to go through each window let me know in another topic.

Comment: Direct access to the document like this will be either slow or broken after Firefox goes multiprocess later this year.

Comment: Aw dang, thats how I do everything my my bootstrapped add-ons though. It's the basis of bootstrap bolierplate. Whats the recommended way for bootstrap to support multipprocess?

Comment: The new [Message Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_message_manager) api. If you continue to use synchronous access to content, your code may either break or use [CPOWS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Cross_Process_Object_Wrappers) aka cross-process object wrappers.

Comment: Thx man! Im worried man that's going to tick off a lot of devs :( It would have been nice if they could have kept things same. Do you know where I can test this stuff? Is it nightly with pref enabled only? Or can I do it in beta?

Comment: Nightly only for now, and it will be a few months before release. This will piss off devs, which is one of the reasons it has taken so long. CPOWS will probably allow a lot of add-ons to continue to work.